# Display UIView subclass which contains other UIViews

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I want to package some UIViews suchs as UIButton, UIImageView in a single UIView.
When I try to display that view, it is not showing up on my RootViewController:

Here is the code of my UIView subclass :

```
#import "Hover.h"

@implementation Hover


- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        UIImage *hover = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hover.png"];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imageView.image = hover;
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, hover.size.width, hover.size.height);
        imageView.alpha = 0.75;
        [self addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And here is the RootViewController class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    Hover *hover = [[Hover alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:hover];
    [hover release];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

The "hover view" is not displayed! However, when I add a single UIImageView to my RootViewController, it works!

Comment: You also need to override `UIView`'s designated initializer which is `initWithFrame:` to be sure your view is initialized properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your view to display, you should override the `-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;`, instead of writing a custom initializer.

Try this way :

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self) {
        // do init here...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Also, in the `-(void)viewDidLoad;` method, first send `[super viewDidLoad];`, and then alloc/init the view.

Comment: It worked, just needed to move [super viewDidLoad] to the top! Thanks

Comment: Have a look to `UIView`'s doc, about the initializer... you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            Hover *hover = [[Hover alloc] init];

            [self.navigationController.visibleViewController.view addSubview:hover];

            [hover release];



                // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }
```

Comment: Nice copy / paste, explanations please ?

Comment: we have to add the view to visibleviewcontroller's view of navigation controller otherwise it wont apear

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess at a glance: If you're using a navigationcontroller, you should initWithRootViewController. You can't add a view to a navigationcontroller directly, Use push instead.

HTH
Marcus